# Vue Auto Completion in template Visual Studio Code

Tags: vue.js, vetur

I'm using typescript + vue + vetur.
In the single file component, I do not have autocompletion in the template part.

E.g. `<tempalte> <div v-for="article in articles" /> </template>` if I place my cursor over the "articles" no tooltip  pops up.

In the script, it works fine.

What can be the issue with that?

Comment: There's a typo in your opening `<tempalte>` tag, perhaps that's why?

Comment: no it's not that